# Tag moxie? I mean MOXIE tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've recently asked three questions related to [MOXIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Oxygen_ISRU_Experiment) and created a [moxie-oxygen-generator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moxie-oxygen-generator) tag. I'm not sure

1. that that is the best name for the tag
2. that a tag is even needed; we already have [oxygen](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxygen)

> [oxygen](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxygen) Questions regarding consumption **and production** of oxygen

In addition to three questions already tagged [moxie-oxygen-generator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moxie-oxygen-generator) there are five more questions that could be tagged

- [Maturity of in-situ steel production conceptualization?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30028/12102)
- [What is required to produce rocket quality methane fuel and oxygen from Mars' atmosphere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13393/12102)
- [In-situ oxygen on Mars - what is MOXIE and SpaceX' ITS relation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21816/12102)
- [How plausible are the predictions made by Stephen Petranek at TED?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17117/12102)
- [How will Mars terraforming missions really work, how do pioneers like SpaceX plan on conquering Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35801/12102)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if there's already 21 posts on the topic, I think that's a good case for a tag.

EDIT: Given that only a handful of those posts were questions, this does seem more borderline.

Comment: oh, most posts were answers, I've updated the question to show that there are only five more questions that seem to be taggable, though I would suppose that there will be more as the mission draws closer and then happens.

Comment: @uhoh Edited my answer as well